What's the result of applying a CNOT gate followed by a Hadamard?
Say I have the following circuit

And the input is $|\psi\rangle=\frac12(|00\rangle+|11\rangle+|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$. To find the output sate, I would first apply the CNOT to the second bit, controlling on the first bit:
$$CNOT|\psi\rangle=\frac12(|00\rangle+|10\rangle+|01\rangle+|11\rangle)$$
After doing this, I woul apply the Hadamard to the first qubit which results in:
$$H(CNOT|\psi\rangle)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}((|00\rangle+|10\rangle)+(|00\rangle-|10\rangle)+(|01\rangle+|11\rangle)+(|01\rangle-|11\rangle))$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|01\rangle)=|0\rangle|+\rangle$$
Is it possible for someone to verify this as I am unsure about the Hadamard portion in my math?

Your formuals are correct 
It is also makes sense as if you would apply the reverse order on the output, you will get the input mentioned

Your calculations are correct. Make the following three observations:

$|\psi\rangle=|{++}\rangle$,
$X|+\rangle=|+\rangle$, so $\text{CNOT}|{++}\rangle=|{++}\rangle$,
$H|{+}\rangle=|0\rangle$.

Putting it all together we have
\begin{align}
(H\otimes I)\circ\text{CNOT}|{++}\rangle=H\otimes I|{++}\rangle=|0+\rangle
\end{align}
as you found.

What does the circle operator ∘ mean in this context? Is it the Hadamard product?

It's just function composition.
